# Cannot read property value of undefined (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX script

Here is code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Profile_Data_Questions", "Interwier")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var question1 = data[0];

            $(".list").append('<div class="something" style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question1 + '</div>' +
                '<div  class="something" style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question2 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question3 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question4 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question5 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question6 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question7 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question8 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question9 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="something"  style="cursor: pointer;width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;">' + question1.Question10 + '</div>');
            var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

            for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                if (divs[i].innerHTML == "") {
                    divs[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And here is code on back end:

```
public ActionResult Profile_Data_Questions()
    {
        var dataforprofile = TempData["FIO"];
        var profiledataquestions = db.QuestionBlocks
            .Where(x => x.Interview.Interwiers.Any(y => y.FIO == dataforprofile))
            .Where(x => x.Question1 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question2 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question3 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question4 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question5 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question6 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question7 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question8 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question9 != null)
            .Where(x => x.Question10 != null)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ID = x.Block_ID.ToString(),
                Question1 = x.Question1,
                Question2 = x.Question2,
                Question3 = x.Question3,
                Question4 = x.Question4,
                Question5 = x.Question5,
                Question6 = x.Question6,
                Question7 = x.Question7,
                Question8 = x.Question8,
                Question9 = x.Question9,
                Question10 = x.Question10,
            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(profiledataquestions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have this error on View

> Cannot read property 'Question1' of undefined

I set breakpoint on back-end code and data is written

[image]

Where can be problem?

Thank's for help so much!

Comment: `data` is empty, check its content with `console.log(data)`

Comment: It is not clear where do you receive the error. Do you have it in browser in the javascript callback or do you have it on the serve-side while rendering Profile.cshtml?

Comment: I got it in browser@IonutUngureanu

Comment: As @bviale suggested did you check `console.log(data)`

Comment: then probably @bviale is correct. Inspect the value of the data in the success function. It is possible that your data filter on the server side returns an empty list.

Comment: It must be coming back with no data but still a 200 status code.  I just tested that bit of code and it works fine.  It's worth inspecting the request in the chrome developer tools too to see exactly what the response is coming back from your ajax request.

Comment: Yes, you were right @Luke

Comment: What was causing it?  I'm intrigued now :)

Comment: I has bug with TempData :)@Luke